# Pull to refresh on the notifications pull out results in it closing?

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, android-app

If you bring up the notifications pull out (either by pressing the notifications icon on the top bar or swiping from the right) and then pull to refresh, it refreshes and then closes again.

[image]

I have tested this many times just to make sure I wasn't moving slightly right when I pulled down to refresh, but this does seem to be the actual behaviour. I would have expected this to refresh the notifications pull out without closing it.

Comment: I'm seeing this too. I haven't been able to track down why it's happening, but we're aware of the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 1.0.19 you can't pull to refresh notifications anymore. Opening the notifications will show a refresh button in the action bar instead.

What was happening was that the pull to refresh action had to he *exactly* vertical else the drawer got too eager and closed itself.